# Tycho build fails for maven 3.6.0 + Eclipse 2018-12 + JDK 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I am having a problem building my sample plugin using Tycho. 
Created a sample plugin on eclipse java/j2ee IDE version 2018-12(4.10.0) with PDE support.Integrated tycho through pom.xml(P.S tycho or any tycho util is not pre-intsalled).

My `pom.xml` for the sample plugin is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myeclipse.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.myeclipse.example.id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>1.3.0</tycho-version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse-2018-12</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

On running the build getting below error. Tried all applicable solution suggested for similar problem but no success. Error seems to be due to p2 url, but it is accessible from browser though.

```
    [INFO] Adding repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12
    [ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID '2018-12' from location https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/: Unknown Host: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/content.xml: Unknown host download.eclipse.org -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID '2018-12' from location https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID '2018-12' from location https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.gatherExternalInstallableUnits (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform (ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform (P2DependencyResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoResolver.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    ....
    Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown Host: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/content.xml
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache (CacheManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.createCache (RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile (SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load (SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad (MetadataRepositoryManager.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository (AbstractRepositoryManager.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository (AbstractRepositoryManager.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository (MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository (RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository (RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.gatherExternalInstallableUnits (TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:270)
    ...
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0 (InetAddress.java:1280)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve (SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open (ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect (DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute (AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest (HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run (AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run (Worker.java:63)
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

Comment: error is `UnknownHostException`. Check your internet connection or if you are in a proxy network, add relevant proxy to maven.

Comment: As an FYI (and slightly off-topic), tycho builds are known to have problems with Maven 3.6.1 - see [MNG-6642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6642).

Comment: @SteveC Unrelated to this issue.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I know - I figured that someone else searching for maven 3.6 and Tycho would hit this page; hence the FYI

Comment: Proxy settings were in place, but not referred by eclipse. This is fixed but still no luck.  Getting new exception that, "Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to connect to repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12/content.xml 
 and Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
"

Comment: That means the P2 repository is not accessible anymore or simply has been vanished...Do you use a repository manager?

Comment: @khmarbaise, not using any repository manager. I expect to connect to p2 repo or equivalent local repo. As I am unable to connect to p2, any possibility of having local repo? is that right way to do?

Comment: Based on unknown host error message I suppose you are behind a corporate firewall/proxy which does not allow to directly access the P2 repos...

Comment: Sometimes it helps to use http instead of https in repository URLs. Though in this case "UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org" sounds more like a DNS or firewall issue to me.